# Displaying possibilities in word search while getting number of words

Tags: java, search, cpu-word, wordsearch

I have this code here which is part of a word search game. I'm trying to make it to when the user quits or when time ends it will display all the words that were present in the grid. That, so far i have achieved. My problem is that i would also like to display the amount of words that were present, so a number. How can i make it to where it displays "There were (number of words) present words" at the top, then the words below it.

```
try {
                            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("allWordsEn.txt");
                            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
                            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                            String strLine;
                            int presentWords = 0;
                            System.out.println("There were " + presentWords + " present words. They are:");
                            //Read File Line By Line
                            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   
                            {
                              if(canFind(strLine, t40)) 
                              {
                                presentWords++;
                                System.out.print(strLine + " ");
                              }
                            }
                            //Close the input stream
                            in.close();
```

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream to read text http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/java-memes-which-refuse-to-die.html

Answer (score 0):

Use a [String Builder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to build up your list of words like so:

```
    //Before the loop
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    //inside the loop
    s.append(strLine + " ");
    //after the loop
    System.out.println("There were " + presentWords + " present words. They are:" + s.toString());
```